# SceneKit SCNPhysicsBody performance

Tags: swift, scenekit

SceneKit SCNPhysicsBody performance doesn't seem to take advantage of the multiple cores.
I created a quick bit of code that puts a bunch of small spheres on top of a cube where they drop under gravity.  As the number of spheres increases things get very slow.  I don't see a way of getting optimal multicore performance.  Anyone have any ideas?

I did some quick tests with a stopwatch and observing the simulation to a specific point launching 1,5 and 8 instances of the app.

1 instance running : 15 seconds

2 instances running : 25 seconds

8 instances running : 35 seconds

It is clear that the multcores are not being used optimally for simulation with just one instance.

```
func createCubeWithSpheres(bottomLeft: SCNVector3, topRight: SCNVector3, radiusOfSpheres: Double) -> SCNNode {
  // Create the box using the bottomLeft and topRight coordinates
  let box = SCNBox(
    width: topRight.x - bottomLeft.x,
    height: topRight.y - bottomLeft.y,
    length: topRight.z - bottomLeft.z,
    chamferRadius: 0.0
  )
  let node = SCNNode(geometry: box)

  // Add a static physics body to the box
  node.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .static, shape: nil)

  // Calculate the dimensions of the box
  let width = box.width
  let height = box.height
  let depth = box.length

  // Calculate the maximum number of spheres that can fit inside the box
  let maxNumSpheresWidth = Int(width / (radiusOfSpheres * 2))
  let maxNumSpheresHeight = Int(height / (radiusOfSpheres * 2))
  let maxNumSpheresDepth = Int(depth / (radiusOfSpheres * 2))
  let maxNumSpheres = maxNumSpheresWidth * maxNumSpheresHeight * maxNumSpheresDepth

  // Create an array to hold the spheres
  var spheres = [Sphere]()

  // Create the spheres and add them to the array
  for zIndex in 0..<maxNumSpheresDepth {
    for yIndex in 0..<maxNumSpheresHeight {
      for xIndex in 0..<maxNumSpheresWidth {
        let xPos = bottomLeft.x + radiusOfSpheres + (radiusOfSpheres * 2) * CGFloat(xIndex)
        let yPos = bottomLeft.y + radiusOfSpheres + (radiusOfSpheres * 2) * CGFloat(yIndex)
        let zPos = bottomLeft.z + radiusOfSpheres + (radiusOfSpheres * 2) * CGFloat(zIndex)
        let sphere = Sphere(radius: radiusOfSpheres, position: SCNVector3(xPos, yPos, zPos))
        spheres.append(sphere)
      }
    }
  }

  // Add the spheres to the box's node
  for sphere in spheres {
    node.addChildNode(sphere.node)
  }
  return node
}

class Sphere {
    let node = SCNNode()
    
    // Initialize the sphere with a radius and position.
    init(radius: CGFloat, position: SCNVector3? = nil) {
        node.geometry = SCNSphere(radius: radius)
        if let position = position {
            node.position = position
        }
        // Add a physics body to the sphere so that it can interact with other objects.
        node.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .dynamic, shape: nil)

        // Add a "stickiness" to the sphere by applying a static electric field to it.
//        let electricField = SCNPhysicsField.electric()
//        electricField.strength = 10 // Adjust this value to increase or decrease the stickiness of the sphere.
//        node.physicsField = electricField
    }
}

let box = createCubeWithSpheres(bottomLeft: SCNVector3(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0), topRight: SCNVector3(x: 5.0, y: 5.0, z: 5.0), radiusOfSpheres: 0.1)
        
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(box)
```

Anyway to speed this up with one instance running without giving up collision accuracy?

[image]

Comment: In my opinion, and what I have observed with SceneKit your example has way too much SCNNode objects. There are more than 2000 of them and almost 2.5 million triangles. This might knock out SceneKit completely. A SCNNode is quite a complex object with so many properties and parameters, and SceneKit must calculate all of them for each and every rendered frame. What I observed is a maximum of around 200 - 300 Nodes, otherwise things become slow and the framerate begins to drop. SceneKit is just not designed fo so many individual objects.

Comment: @ZAY it was my intention to test how many SCNNodes objects it can handle and see if it is taking full advantage of multi-cores.  Apparently it is not as you can see from my simple test that simulating 8X the number of SCNNodes by running separate processes that the time is only roughly 2X.  
The reason for my question was to get input if there was anything that could be done about this without giving up collision accuracy and without doing things in a completely different way.  Or if there were some other solution that Apple provides for many object collisions.